# Paypal API with angular and cURL

Tags: angularjs, curl, paypal

Currently I'm working with paypal API and flowing with this document [make your first call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/).

When I sent a request through angular $http to paypal, I got a Status Code 415. It's seems like I missed something, does anyone can help me? :)

```
here is my code
 $http({
        url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                  'auth-token': 'EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp',
                  'Accept-Language': 'en_US'
                  },
        data: { 'grant_type': 'client_credentials' }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data)
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the Paypal doc

> Tip: If you're using Windows, we recommend you make cURL calls using a
>   Bash shell. If you're not using cURL calls, set the content-type to
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded for this request.

Try set the `content_type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Great! You may want to accept my answer as the correct one :)

Comment: hi, Rebornixm, I  encountered a new problem. Could you help me again, thanks a lot. :) [new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384174/paypal-api-with-angular-400-bad-request)